# Skein relation for the Jones polynomial - Example not working out

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

I've decided to learn some knot theory during this summer, using The Knot Book. Today, I showed that the Jones polynomial satisfies the Skein relation $$t^{-1}V(L_+) - tV(L_-) + (t^{-1/2}-t^{1/2})V(L_0)$$.

After showing this, I decided to work out an example. I picked the right-handed trefoil. We have previously calculated that the Jones polynomial of the riht-handed trefoil is $t+t^3-t^4$. All the crossings are negative, so I substituted the Jones polynomial of the trefoil for $V(L_-)$, and the switched the crossing to obtain $L_+$ and $L_0$. I obtained that $L_+$ can be turned into the unknot by a couple of Reidemeister moves, and hence decided that $V(L_+) = 1$. Finally, $L_0$ turns out to be the Hopf link, which has Jones polynomial $-t-t^{-1}$. So I substituted $V(L_0) = -t-t^{-1}$.

Then, looking at my Skein relation, I have:

$$t^{-1}(1)-t(t+t^3-t^4) + (t^{-1/2}-t^{1/2})(-t-t^{-1}) = t^{-1} - t^2 - t^4 + t^5 - t^{1/2} - t^{-3/2} + t^{3/2} + t^{-1/2} \neq 0$$

Why is this not working out correctly? What am I missing? I've checked that my polynomials for the trefoil and the Hopf link is correct, and I've checked my algebra, so I assume I'm missing something more fundamental.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part you are missing is that mirror images in the Jones polynomial take $t$ and replace it with $t^{-1}$. Also, I suppose you mean the Skein relation at the top equals 0. Another mistake is Hopf Link's Jones Polynomial. If you look at page 15 of Jones' [presentation](https://math.berkeley.edu/~vfr/jonesakl.pdf) on his polynomial, we see the positive Hopf link has a polynomail of  $-t^{\frac{5}{2}}-t^{\frac{1}{2}}$. (Note: It appears that Wolfram's [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HopfLink.html) is wrong.) But in our problem, we have the negative Hopf Link, which has Jones polynomial $-t^{-\frac{5}{2}}-t^{-\frac{1}{2}}$.  And the right handed trefoil, or the mirror image will have Jones polynomial $-t^{-4}+t^{-3}+t^{-1}$. Making these changes we should have:

$$t^{-1}(1)-t\left( -t^{-4}+t^{-3}+t^{-1} \right)+\left(t^{-\frac{1}{2}}-t^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)\left( -t^{-\frac{5}{2}}-t^{-\frac{1}{2}}\right)=0$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you! I was checking my answers using Wolfram's Mathworld, which is part of why I was so so confused.